# PHP REGEX fine-tuning capturing

Tags: php, regex

I have to process text that comes from student essays (texts can be VERY large).

I need in PHP a preg_match for dates inside that strings which may come in this way:

```
...blah blah blah (1994) blah blah blah ... 
...blah blah blah (nov-1994) blah blah blah ... 
...blah blah blah (november-1994) blah blah blah ...
...blah blah blah (1994-nov) blah blah blah ...
...blah blah blah (1994-november) blah blah blah ...
```

The dates in the strings may come with '( )' or with '[ ]'

I have done it this way:

```
if (preg_match('/\w{0,8}-?(19|20)\d{2}-?\w{0,8}/', $string, $s)) {
 # code
}
```

**which is right and do its job but its capturing some unrelated strings like**

```
... blah blah blah (SKU_1956) blah blah blah ...
... blah blah blah [INFERNO2000] blah blah blah ...
... blah blah blah [like-2000-me] blah blah blah ...
```

I dont seem to be able to do it, so I need help to fine-tuning this regexp to only capture if

- start with either ( [
- *may* be a single word and if it exists, MUST end in -
- MUST BE a year in the lap 19xx-20xx
- *may* be a single word and if it exists, MUST start with -
- end with either ) ]

The word is limited to 8 chars because of the longest month (like december)

There is a huge amount of non-related strings captured, thats why I want to fine-tuning it.

Comment: Try something like [`[([]((\w{1,8})-((?:20|19)\d{2})|(?3)-(?2)|(?3))[])]`](https://regex101.com/r/DG4QwY/1/)

Comment: You will need to specify the months to realize this. Because \w or [a-z] does not make a difference between a word "like" and "nov". You also need to escape the "-"-character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the RegEx [`[(\[](([a-zA-Z]{1,8}-)?(19|20)\d{2}|(19|20)\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{1,8})[)\]]`](https://regex101.com/r/qUwg5Z/3/)

- `[(\[] ... [)\]]` matches anything inside `()` or `[]`
- `([a-zA-Z]{1,8}-)?(19|20)\d{2}` matches `month-YEAR` with the month being optional

  - `([a-zA-Z]{1,8}-)?` matches an alphabetical char between `1` and `8` times, and a `-`
  - `(19|20)\d{2}` matches `19..` or `20..`
- `(19|20)\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{1,8})` matches `YEAR-month`

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/qUwg5Z/3/)

Comment: what about "like-1994"?

Comment: yes, (like-1994) is also captured... 

BTW there were a small typo error:

it should capture the 4 year digits, so I think Zenoo answer should be

[(\[](([a-zA-Z]{1,8}-)?(19\d{2}|20\d{2})|(19\d{2}|20\d{2})\-[a-zA-Z]{1,8})[)\]]

https://regex101.com/r/rGPPzh/1

THUMBS UP FOR (http://regex101.com)

Didn't knew that site !!!

Think that close the question, I will be dealing with the text (if it is a month) in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could list all the valid [date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in an array:

`$formats = ["M-Y", "Y", "F-Y", "Y-F", "Y-M"];`

and then loop them to test if you can create a valid [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

As the regex pattern you could capture what is between the parenthesis in group 1:

[`/\(([^)]+)\)/`](https://regex101.com/r/fupFOz/1)

```
$strings = [
    "...blah blah blah (1994) blah blah blah ... ",
    "...blah blah blah (nov-1994) blah blah blah ... ",
    "...blah blah blah (november-1994) blah blah blah ...",
    "...blah blah blah (1994-nov) blah blah blah ...",
    "...blah blah blah (1994-november), (1994), (nov-1994) blah blah blah ...",
    "...blah blah blah (1994-november) blah blah blah ..."
];
$formats = ["M-Y", "Y", "F-Y", "Y-F", "Y-M"];
$pattern = '/\(([^)]+)\)/';
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
        foreach ($formats as $format) {
            if (DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $match) !== false) {
                echo "$string contains valid date: <b>$match</b>" . PHP_EOL;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/kC8AB)